# create/remove row permission in IBM i (as400) SQL

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

In Db2 for IBM i, I can create row permission like this.

```
-- enable row access control
ALTER TABLE QIWS.QCUSTCDT ACTIVATE ROW ACCESS CONTROL;

-- create permission MYPERMISSION999
CREATE PERMISSION MYPERMISSION999 ON SALES.ORDHED
FOR ROWS WHERE VERIFY_GROUP_FOR_USER(SESSION_USER,'MYGROUP') = 1
               AND SCODE = SESSION_USER                  
ENFORCED FOR ALL ACCESS

ENABLE;
COMMIT;
ALTER TABLE SALES.ORDHED ACTIVATE ROW ACCESS CONTROL;
COMMIT;
```

If I Deactivate row access control, rules seem to go away, but if I ACTIVATE old rules come back.

```
 ALTER TABLE SALES.ORDHED           
     DEACTIVATE ROW ACCESS CONTROL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DROP PERMISSION MYPERMISSION999;
```

Should do it

Comment: The key here is the difference between a specific permission and an overall setting on the table. The specific permission stays in place, whether activated or deactivated, unless you DROP it as @Paul suggests.